# Find all packages that uses a given File in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, aptitude, dpkg

I'd like to list all the packages that uses a given file.
 I'm willing to use any tool (such as dpkg, dlocate, apt-file etc.),
Please do mind when I say 'use' I don't mean necessarily only owns/installs the file, I'd like to know which package also reference it, link against it etc.

here's my use case:

I have installed both KVM and VirtualBox and ended up using only VirtualBox, as it turns out VirtualBox and KVM competes for resources of some sort, fortunately enough for me I don't use KVM so I just uninstalled it.

by issuing:

```
sudo apt-get purge kvm
```

But it wasn't enough and when I tried to run VirtualBox on a subsequent boot I got the following error:

> Error: failed to start machine. Error message: VirtualBox can't operate in VMX root mode. Please disable the KVM kernel extension, recompile your kernel and reboot (VERR_VMX_IN_VMX_ROOT_MODE)

looking at the loaded modules revealed that the kvm kernel modules were still loaded

```
mcradle:~> lsmod | grep -i kvm
kvm_intel              39416  0
kvm                   244969  1 kvm_intel
```

tuned to a web search which suggested to purge qemu-kvm

```
sudo apt-get purge qemu-kvm
```

this did the trick, now my question is:  how could I have gotten to this conclusion systematically without the web-magic-dust?
In particular It would be nice to know how can one tell which package depends on a given **file**?

Please do mind that dlocate -S is not good enough because it shows the file's owner package and I wanted to find the package that causes 'kvm.ko' to be loaded!

```
mcradle:/etc# dlocate -S kvm.ko
linux-image-2.6.32-25-generic-pae: /lib/modules/2.6.32-25-generic-pae/kernel/arch/x86/kvm/kvm.ko
```

if 'apt-rdepends -r' would have accepted files instead of packages that could have been exactly what I'm after.

Thanks in advance and I hope the question is clear.

Comment: this question might be a better fit on askubuntu

Comment: @aking1012: This question is not specific to Ubuntu; the same package management tools exist on all Debian derivatives, and the underlying issue applies to any Linux distribution and beyond. So while it is on-topic on Ask Ubuntu, it's a better fit here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general way of finding packages that use a given file. You can combine `dpkg -S` or `dlocate` to find what package contains a file, with `apt-rdepends` to find what packages depend on that package. But that won't cover all cases, and it won't tell you which files each package depends on (not that this is really meaningful: dependencies apply to packages as a whole, and often they can't be pinpointed to a particular file in the depended-upon package).

One case you won't be able to find through dependencies is dependencies on essential packages (those for which the metadata includes `Essential: yes`). Every system must have the complete collection of essential packages, or if you like every package is assumed to depend on every essential package. Case in point: `kvm.ko` is a kernel module, belonging to the kernel package, which is essential.

Another case you can't always find through dependencies is plug-ins. Many programs will load whatever plug-ins they find installed, and will run even if the plug-in is not there, so the program usually declares no dependency on the plug-in. (The plug-in may declare a dependency on some kind of plug-in framework that the package providing the main program executable depends on, but that's not always the case.) Case in point: the `kvm` kernel module is an optional component of the kvm virtual machine; you can run `/usr/bin/kvm` even if the `kvm` kernel module is not loaded, it'll just be slower.

Here the message from VirtualBox is so generic and playing-it-safe that it's misleading. The message assumes that the KVM extension is compiled into the kernel, but on your system it's really a module that can be unloaded. Merely unloading the module is enough to satisfy VirtualBox: just run `rmmod kvm_amd kvm_intel kvm`. You can also keep the `qemu-kvm` package from loading the `kvm` module by editing `/etc/init.d/qemu-kvm` or `/etc/init/qemu-kvm.conf` (depending whether your Ubuntu release has a SysVinit script or an Upstart script) and commenting out the module-loading line, or preventing the service from starting at boot time.

Comment: Yes I know how to solve the problem presented (in my case purging kvm and qemu-kvm was good enough), I wanted to understand what is that I don't know and equip myself with the tools should I face a similar problem in the future, and I'm still not sure for example how to tell which package causes a module to load (perhaps this should have been my question)

Comment: @Mcradle: The main point of my answer is that there is no fully general way. Any program could potentially cause a module to load at any point (for example, if qemu had been engineered slightly differently, it might have loaded the `kvm` module from the `qemu` executable instead of from a boot script).

Comment: I agree, but why does qemu even assumes that the kvm modules are compiled and available? the kernel package may not be even enabling the drivers at all.

Comment: @Mcradle: It doesn't assume that the modules are there, it just tries to load them (doing nothing if they aren't there or aren't supported by the hardware).

Comment: so this fully demonstrates your point of 'opportunistic usage' of other packages files without registering this as a dependency anywhere. I totally get it.

Answer (score 1):

Web pixie dust? By their powers combined, a team of package tools will shine a blinding light and make the darkness recoil!

1. use `dlocate -S` to find the owner package
2. use `aptitude remove -sy $pkg` to find out all dependent packages (`-syD` to add detail; `aptitude why` to find just one dependency chain).

Or in one step:

1. `aptitude remove -sy $(dlocate -S /path/to/file |sed 's#:.*##' |uniq )`

Comment: thanks. I don't think it's going to work for the case I've presented because 'dlocate -S' returns 'linux-image-2.6.32-25-generic-pae' which is the kernel package that I don't want to uninstall (one would imagine this is either impossible or bares severe consequences)

Comment: `-sy` is in fact simulating an uninstall, and tells you what depends on the package. It runs without root privileges.

Answer (score -1):

[apt-file](http://vivapinkfloyd.blogspot.com/2008/07/how-to-use-apt-file-to-see-what-files.html) should work for that. I haven’t tested that

Comment: Thanks for the answe. I think that 'apt-file search /lib/modules/2.6.32-25-generic-pae/kernel/arch/x86/kvm/kvm.ko' is only showing the package that installed the file, apt-file does not seem to have other action that would be of interest.

Comment: Sorry I was in hurt and doesn’t read well